# "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" why?

Tags: reactjs, json

I get this error after of parsing json file. before parsing, it showed json file in output(tag p).

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import text from "./json.js";

const cities = JSON.parse(text);

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            hint: ''
        }
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{cities}</p>
                <input value={this.state.value} placeholder={this.state.hint} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

json.js:

```
(function getJson(){
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function (){
        export const text = this.responseText;
        }
    xhttp.open("GET", "./cities.json");
    xhttp.send();
})()
```

cities.json:

https://www.uplooder.net/files/d5f677d8df6a69e6bd17dba5916ee4d0/cities.json.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your whole question (including any necessary code/text, such as a minimal example of `cities.json`) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Also, what does `json.js` have to do with it? It's not used as far as one can tell from the first code block.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oops!! I made a mistake! I must be write [import text from "./json.js"]. I edited.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My second mistake, I did not put json.js inside src folder. I now placed that. I placed link to json file, because my json file is very long. How should I put such files?

Comment: See my first comment: You include a **minimal example** of it, not the whole thing, **in** the question.

Comment: The question is entirely incorrect, now this answer is incorrect too, such a waste of time, the best advice for you is to make sure your question is correct also , do not edit a question if it will change the entire answer but create another question instead

Comment: @JCue - Indeed, the question changed *markedly* in the edit and shouldn't have been posted in its original state.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, the thought of not needing the fetch file because he imported the './cities.json' got me and that's the reason for the error, now my answer is incorrect LOL

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am sorry for my mistakes,realy. I have a file with json suffix. inside it, only exist an array.( ["one","tow", ... ] ). Is it enough to import and use it? in fact, the json file is extra, right?

Comment: Be careful... be very careful, you risk getting a question ban if your next question is also downvoted. Spend time making sure there are no writing mistakes in the problem. And don't accept answers that do not resolve your problems. Users will see the green checkmark and believe the problem has been resolved.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I was really confused. Delete it and ask from the beginning?

Comment: You can't delete it because 1. it has received two answers 2. One of the answers has been upvoted. Just make sure your next question is proofread, and you haven't forgotten any relevant information.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The problem is that now I do not know at all what is wrong with my question!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.js` has a syntax error: `export` declarations cannot appear anywhere but the top level of a module, but yours is inside a callback function inside another function.

If you're using a bundler, it would probably let you import `cities.json` directly using `import` (details varies by bundler).

If not, you could use [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) if your environment supports it:

```
const getCitiesText = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("./cities.json");
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    return await response.text();
};
export const text = await getCitiesText();
```

That exports the text of the file as you seem to want, but if you wanted to export the parsed array instead, you'd use `json()` instead of `text()` (and probably change the name of the export):

```
const getCities = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("./cities.json");
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    return await response.json();
};
export const cities = await getCities();
```

If you have to support environments that don't have top-level `await`, you can't export the contents of `cities.json`, you can only export a **promise** of that content:

```
const getCities = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("./cities.json");
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    return await response.json();
};
export const citiesPromise = getCities(); // No `await` here
```

Anything importing `citiesPromise` will have to `await` it to get the actual contents.